# How to count number of views of a particular videos in Nodejs just like youtube

Tags: node.js, youtube

I am using Nodejs. Right Now we counting views on the basis of I.P. If requests comes from different IP then we increment count by 1 . For getting the IP we are using `req.connection.remoteAddress` .

Right now we are in development mode. Is this a good way or we need to something different ?

Comment: Do your users have any sort of login?

Comment: Nope they are normal and doesn't require login

Answer (score 1):

Such a system is too easy to bypass by proxies.

so I recommend to

1. combine it with [fingerprintjs](http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs2/)
2. enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to protect from cheats by services where users payed per action (in your case to watch the videos).
3. store user identity with something like [evercookie](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie)

Comment: Yes correctly it is easily bypass by proxies and I think when multiple users are connected through wifi then IP is same. This is another issue we face